# Can't find RegistryKey-Class even when Microsoft.Win32 is used

Tags: c#, namespaces, registry, visual-studio-2017

I'm currently working on a project in which I need to work with registry keys. As read in several tutorials, the namespace `Microsoft.Win32` offers a class called RegistryKey to work with the registry.

My problem is that Visual Studio can't find the class although I imported the namespace using `using Microsoft.Win32;`.

Normally I only type in just a few letters and I already get a suggestion for the class I'm searching for. But now Visual Studio doesn't even suggest the class.

Did I forget anything? Are there other namespaces I need to use? 
I'm using Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise - maybe it's because of that?

Comment: `RegistryKey` class is in `Microsoft.Win32` namespace (`mscorlib` asembly) and should be visible. You could try with some asnwers from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37015074/visual-studio-intellisense-not-showing-some-classes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I forgot to mention that I'm creating a .NET Core Application. As a result I had to download the required class using the **NuGet Package Manager** because .Net Core applications manage their references in NuGet packages!

Answer (score 1):

The registry is simply not part of .NET Core. Take a look at Windows Compatibility Pack
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/core/porting/windows-compat-pack

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the `Microsoft.Win32.Registry` Nuget Package.