# visual studio analyser reports false errors in C# code

Tags: c#, visual-studio

The code compiles fine but the standard Analysers of Visual Studio is reporting a lot of errors. e.g.:

```
using cleverDev.WpfUtils.WPF;
```

Error reported:

> Type or Namespace name 'WpfUtils' does not exist in namespace cleverDev

But everything is fine. The Namespace exists, the code is compiled fine and also resharper finds the namespace.

The reference (Project Reference) bringing in the namespace is also working fine in other solutions.
I already tried to delete the reference and recreate it, bring it in in different ways, Rebuild a couple of times, nothing helps.

Comment: Sounds like an IntelliSense problem, I suggest that you try the approaches suggested in the answers to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37015074/87698

Comment: @Heinzi  thanks for your quick replay, looks like deleteing the complete .vs folder in this solution resolved the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Commend of @Heinzi included the solution.

I deleted the complete .vs folder of this solution an the problem was gone.

Comment: I am glad to hear that your problem has been solved, you can click '✔' to mark your reply as an answer.