# Why i cant instantiate it and call the "Calculate" method?

Tags: c#, .net

I saw a question on this page https://www.toptal.com/c-sharp/interview-questions 
tryed to implement it in VS, here is is my full code:

```
 public class TopTalInterviewQuestions
 {
    //write code to calculate the circumference of the circle, without modifying the Circle class itself.
    Circle myCircle = new Circle();
    myCircle.??? // here VS does not help me        
}

public sealed class Circle
{
    //public Circle() { }
    private double radius;
    public double Calculate(Func<double, double> op)
    {
        return op(radius);
    }
}
```

Why i cant instantiate it and call the "Calculate" method?
Please. explain it for a beginner.

Comment: The code as shown works, no idea what your problem is. Are you sure you provided everything that reproduces the issue? In particular: which compiler-error do you get?

Comment: which version of VS are you using ? have you built your solution before trying to autocomplet? is autocomplete turned on to begin with? so many questions ...

Comment: circle.Calculate(r => 2 * Math.PI * r) they have the "show the right answer with explanation" on their site as well...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio 2015 Intellisense not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31654667/visual-studio-2015-intellisense-not-working)

Comment: @OndrejSvejdar He's not asking _what arguments should I pass_ rather _why isn't auto-complete_ working I suspect

Comment: @MickyD - its somehow ambigious, the last sentence is "Why i cant instantiate it and call the "Calculate" method?", while in comment it is for sure complaint on intellisense.

Comment: Get Resharper. Problem solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this class:

```
public class TopTalInterviewQuestions
{
    //write code to calculate the circumference of the circle, without modifying the Circle class itself.
    Circle myCircle = new Circle();
    myCircle.??? // here VS does not help me        
}
```

When you're writing the line `myCircle.???`, you're trying to put a statement directly inside of a class declaration. You can't do that; statements need to go inside of methods.

Try something like this:

```
public class TopTalInterviewQuestions
{
    //write code to calculate the circumference of the circle, without modifying the Circle class itself.
    Circle myCircle = new Circle();
    public void MyMethod()
    {
        myCircle.???
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Tanner Swett, it was obvious for e now, when i stucked in the problem i was too tired to figure it out by myself.