# Why is Visual Studio's Intellisense not showing constructors?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, intellisense

I'm using Visual Studio 2015, writing in c++, and the following does not display any Intellisense:

```
class testing
{
    public:
        testing()
        {

        }
};

void main()
{
    testing t( //Y u no show?
}
```

but whenever I type a **.** or **,** where appropriate, or when I'm call a function or a class's function and type a **(**, it does show Intellisense.

Why is that, and how can I fix it? It doesn't matter what class or library I'm using, and I've tried restarting Visual Studio. Is there perhaps a simple way to "clear Intellisense's cache" or something?

I tried cleaning the solution, creating a new solution, and resetting all environment settings (Tools -> Import and Export Settings), all to no avail. Again, Intellisense is working fine overall, except in this one specific case where I'm creating an instance of a class and need to see the constructor's arguments.

Hopefully someone can give me a working solution to this problem or the Visual Studio developers will resolve it eventually, because it's really annoying, but until then I will have to settle for one of these two options to see Intellisense:

```
testing( //no "t" (variable name): triggers Intellisense
testing t(, //comma in the constructor: triggers Intellisense
```

Comment: Do you mean the intellisense not work like this screenshot: https://1drv.ms/i/s!Atv5QNuFrncKgmL1ZXH1dR381SZc. If this issue persists for all class file under C++ solution, you can have a try with some troubleshot methods: 1. Delete folders (C:\Users\<your users name>\AppData\Local & Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0. 2. Open an administrative CMD window and navigate to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE and run the following commands: devenv /resetuserdata or safemode 3. Repair VS

Comment: Right, I don't see that, and when I press Ctrl+Space or Ctrl+J I get a generic Intellisense as detailed in the comments below. I'll try this later and get back to you.

Comment: The first two options didn't fix it. The latter is too much work for a small reward.

Comment: Hi Andrew, when you type '(' after testing t, does it auto complete with ')'? If not, you can go to Tools-Options-Text Editor-C/C++-General and check 'Automatic brace completion' and save, then type testing t(,) or testing () to test the intellisense. I found if type testing (), the cursor in the middle of '()' and the intellisense appears, type testing t () need to add a , into the () and the cursor after the , to trigger the intelisense display.

Comment: Yes, the parenthesis is auto-completed. Whether or not there is a closing parenthesis has no effect on the Intellisense appearing. Your results are exactly the same as in my edit from a few days ago.

Comment: Since this issue happened recently, did you made any changes or setting to VS or install any windows updates, install other software on the computer? If you already tried the command: devenv /safemode and not works, please try to reset the VS customized setting to the default setting, please go to Tool-Import and Export Settings—Reset all settings and save your current settings, then reset it and create a new project to check this issue again.

Comment: I did not say it happened recently. I only just thought to ask about it since I knew some annoying workarounds but I started to use a new library for which I need to use Intellisense more often. I have already tried that, as mentioned in my post.

Comment: Sorry for my misunderstanding for the sentence 'Your results are exactly the same as in my edit from a few days ago', have you tried my last suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to refresh Intellisense.  To do so, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, or go to Edit>Intellisense>Refresh Local Cache.

I know that after doing this it's helped to get Intellisense back on its feet for me.

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+R did nothing, as far as I know, and there was no Refresh Local Cache option in that menu.

Comment: I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015, Version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3.

Comment: @Andrew what happens when you press Ctrl+J?  That should bring up a list of available options.

Comment: The same thing that happens when I press Ctrl+Space: it shows me a very generic Intellisense, starting with #, #define, and #elif, and ending with ___mb_cur_max_l_func, ___MKID, and ~.

Comment: Essentially, the same Intellisense that shows up when I'm performing the operation in WinMain or on any empty line outside of all scopes.

Comment: @Andrew have you tried what [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31671273/6530134) states?

Comment: Yes. I do not use ReSharper, but "Auto list members" is checked and "Parameter information" is grayed out and cannot be checked for c++.