# Visual Studo: Cant build/rebuild/clean after git merge

Tags: c#, .net, git, visual-studio-2015

I work in a large solution, shared by several different project teams from different companies. Pending an upgrade of the CMS, I have been tasked with merging our code from the old platform version, with the new code in the upgraded solution.

After spending hours on a complicated git merge, all that was left was the .sln file. After I tried resolving the conflicts, **I can't build/clean/rebuild the solution.** Nothing happens when I click either option, it's like I never clicked at all.

**What can I do to get my .sln file to comply?** I've used diff-tools to no avail, since every version of the .sln looks completely different, with unreadable guids and lines.

**What I've tried so far:**

- Restarting VS
- Repairing VS
- using the .sln file from our legacy code
- using the .sln file form the upgraded code
- using a .sln based on the upgraded code, where I just tried adding the lines that our project added to the sln in between the legacy code and the upgraded code.

Grateful for your time and help.

Comment: Do you have anything in the Output window?

Comment: how many project in this .sln? Merging the .sln file is always a little strange. You can check a couple of things, open the sln file in a text editor of your choice and check if the GUIDs for the projects are all in the same case, things like that. In all honesty, when I had a really bad merge I just removed all the projects and re-added them. Figured it would've taken less time then trying to figure it out.

Comment: I've had similar issues with Git on VS.  I did everything you've stated up there.  reset the users settings, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31644895/razor-intellisense-not-working-in-vs-2015/33975363#33975363  .  This one fixed an issue with the Git plugin for me.

Comment: @Valentin: Nothing in the output window. As I wrote, it's like I never clicked build/rebuild at all.

Comment: @Peter4499: Is there any risk in this? Most of these projects are owned by other teams, will I perhaps break some of their configurations by removing/adding their projects?

Comment: @Spencer K: Thank you for your suggestions. I tried, however it did not help me.

Comment: @JohnnyK  don't think so but you can always roll back the change, and (as always) make a backup copy of the file

Comment: Is it ok for you to reset your sln file to a commit before the merge. Then, create a patch for the sln file and apply them on your HEAD. You'll get all changes.