# Autocompletion/colorcoding not working for android xamarin in vs2015

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015

[image]

Hello. I'm a beginner building my first android app on visual studio.

When I first created the project, there was colorcoding and autocompletion for android stuff like the TextView, SetContentView, ISharedPreferences in the code.

When I re-opened to keep working on it, all the colorcoding for those were gone, and no auto-completion(suggestions) come up when as I try to type them again.

It's fine when I created a new project. How do I fix this? or what am I doing wrong? the code works fine apart from the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suspect possibly a corruption in a .vs.config file.

Here's what FINALLY worked for me: Start -> Run -> (Or Windows Key + R) Then type "devenv.exe /resetuserdata" (no quotes of course)

Look **[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31644895/razor-intellisense-not-working-in-vs-2015/31777779#31777779)** at my previous answer. Understand that you may have to do a little resetting of your environment once this is done. It's not horrible, just an inconvenience. Please let us know if it works for you.

Comment: Unfortunately doing the "devenv.exe /resetuserdata" didn't fix for me, however your link helped me fix it! thank you for your help :)