# razor views are giving compile time error always in vs 2013

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, visual-studio-2013

in visual studio 2013,when i create a viwe for a particular function=>when ever i change anything in view it gives a error in every line.although it is correct.
[image]

but it is correct means every lines of code is write.every time i need to build the solution to solve the error.its really occurred.
i tried to =>

[Instead of it, try to just delete the contents of this directory with Visual Studio closed then reopen it: %LocalAppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache]=>found on [Razor intellisense not working in VS 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31644895/razor-intellisense-not-working-in-vs-2015)
but not working for me.