# The type arguments for method cannot be inferred from the usage. view Bag and html helper error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am not able to write expression in `TextboxFor()` method in VS 2013. Below is the razor code for Textbox in asp.net mvc.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.User.LicenseNo)
```

which is showing an error in VS 2013 :

> The type arguments for method 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.InputExtensions.TextBoxFor(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly

But when I open the same solution in VS 2017 its working fine.

The same is the case with the following code

```
ViewBag.Title = "Role Configuration";
```

Error in VS 2013:

> One or more types required to compile a dynamic expression cannot be found. Are you missing a reference?

**EDIT**

Below is my Model `UserDetailsModel` used in the view.

```
public class UserDetailsModel
{
    public UserDetailsModel();

    public List<RoleModel> Roles { get; set; }
    public List<CodeItemModel> Status { get; set; }
    public UserModel User { get; set; }
}
public class UserModel
{
    public UserModel();

    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int LicenseNo { get; set; }
}
```

And I have placed the below code at the top of the view (.cshtml file)...

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Role Configuration";
}
```

Comment: Your `UserModel` is not `public`

Comment: updated @StephenMuecke

Comment: View the warnings in the Error List.

Comment: @CodeCaster Checked but no luck..

Comment: What version of MVC are you using? Also check if the references are ok, after opening the project in VS 2013 maybe the version are wrong

Comment: I am using MVC 4. I am also not able to write linq in razor view... but references seem to be ok... @PawełŁukasik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching over and over I came across the link below.. works like a charm..

[clear component model cache and Enjoy coding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43661522/razor-views-are-giving-compile-time-error-always-in-vs-2013)

Answer (score 0):

In Vs2013 change your view to strongly typed meaning:

insert in the beginning of the view

```
 @model "project/classname";
```

and then use only the property of the user

for example:

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => model.LicenseNo)
```

In Vs2017

make sure you have the

Microsoft.CSharp.dll

and also check if the below exists

In Global.asax.cs add ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new RazorViewEngine()); to the Application_Start() method

Comment: I already have the model defined in the beginging....`@model ItemMasterDetailsModel`