# Visual Studio Intellisense/"Assembly Not Referenced" Issues

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

After getting latest in Visual Studio 2015 Community, some of my Razor syntax is showing red Intellisense errors. Items like @Html.TextboxFor() and @Html.CheckboxFor() are throwing the following error:

> The type 'Expression<>' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089

I have attempted the solutions listed under the following: [VS 2015 IntelliSense: Assembly Not Referenced Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31599087/vs-2015-intellisense-assembly-not-referenced-error), [The type 'Expression<>' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31086850/the-type-expression-is-defined-in-an-assembly-that-is-not-referenced).

Neither one of these issues fixed the problem. Are there any other issues that could be causing this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After uninstalling and reinstalling VS again, it appears that the problem has been taken care of. I'm sure that there must be a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

We just resolved this by disabling VS tool extensions, one of them interfered with intellisense and drove us nuts for two days.