# System.Core not added to reference to assembly

Tags: c#, html, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am currently developing a Aspnet MVC Web application. I am using .NET Framework 4.6.1 and Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc v5.2.6.

I added Kendo.Mvc v2018.3.911.545 to my project and started using Grid Kendo. At first there was no problem at all. After some point, I got following error all of a sudden:

> The type 'Expression<>' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced.You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089

I tried these links and none of them worked for me:

[The type 'Expression<>' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31086850/the-type-expression-is-defined-in-an-assembly-that-is-not-referenced)

[VS2017 The type 'Expression<>' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.](https://forums.asp.net/t/2137945.aspx?VS2017%20The%20type%20Expression%20is%20defined%20in%20an%20assembly%20that%20is%20not%20referenced%20You%20must%20add%20a%20reference%20to%20assembly%20System%20Core%20Version%204%200%200%200%20Culture%20neutral%20PublicKeyToken%20b77a5c561934e089%20)

[Compilation error in .NET 4.0 web.config - Linq not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6496223/compilation-error-in-net-4-0-web-config-linq-not-found)

[bogus intellisense error putting red squiggles all over razor views!!](https://forums.asp.net/t/2089626.aspx?bogus%20intellisense%20error%20putting%20red%20squiggles%20all%20over%20razor%20views%20)

[VS 2015 IntelliSense: Assembly Not Referenced Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31599087/vs-2015-intellisense-assembly-not-referenced-error)

Also, I don't want to downgrade Microsoft.Aspnet.Mvc to v.5.2.0 because this action generates new issues at Kendo UI and razor pages.

Also, I tried upgrading .NET Framework to 4.7.1 and downgrading to 4.5 and still no use. I also don't really want to downgrade .NET Framework because while it does not solve my issue, it also generates new ones.

Comment: If you have a reference to System.Core in your references, you could use a Binding Redirect to redirect the dependency of the other assembly to your current System.Core version.

Comment: Didn't work. `<dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Core" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>`

Comment: Then it could be, that your assemblies have different public keys. Find out the public key of the used System.Core assembly. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3045033/getting-the-publickeytoken-of-net-assemblies)

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately...

Answer (score 0):

The code you shared in the comment to your own question should work as it is:

```xml
<dependentAssembly>
   <assemblyIdentity name="System.Core" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
   <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

At least on VS2022, after adding the reference to the assembly in the `Web.config` file, the error IS NOT gone, **but** ONLY AFTER restarting the IDE. I'm not sure why, but after doing this everything was green.

[image]

Additional information about my project:

- Target framework: .NET Framework 4.7.2
- System.Web.MVC version: v5.2.7.0
- System.Web.MVC runtime version: v4.0.30319

Comment: I have changed my position and working at different place. So, unfortunately I am unable to test your answer but if there is anyone correcting your answer I will gladly accept it as correct answer for your good efforts to answer this question.